# firebase load data manually for redundancy

Tags: firebase

In light of yesterdays firebase outage.  When Firebase goes down again is it possible to call ajax api for data and then push it into local firebase SDK client and make use of all its offline capabilities?

Normal ops:

> WebApp ---> Firebase

```
ref.on('value', function(snap) {
    $scope.data = snap.val();
});
```

If Firebase goes down:

> WebApp ---> External API ---> Firebase

```
$http.get('api.company.com/data').success(function(payload) {
    // somehow i need to get the data into the firebase javascript SDK.
    // so when firebase restores then the changes are sync'd
    // eg.
    // ref.on('value', payload, function(snap) {
    //    $scope.data = snap.val(); // is a mock of my payload
    // });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for you to inject data in to the local cache of a Firebase client.

The closest you can get is by writing your own model layer *around* Firebase. But that is going to be pretty involved if you want that model to mimic the Firebase functionality/API.

Comment: thanks.  That is what I though.  Would be a good feature though.